# Does BlockingCollection<T> guarantee removal order?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a bounded blocking queue in an application that was written several years ago.  Let's just say that the implementation is less than stellar, but it's worked.  However, it has some performance problems.  It looks like the .NET 4.0 `BlockingCollection<T>` is the right replacement, but I need to make sure that it is actually a queue.  That is, is it guaranteed to be strictly FIFO if used in a single-producer, single-consumer fashion?

The documentation doesn't specifically say.  The [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) topic does say (in the Remarks):

> `BlockingCollection<T>` is similar to a
>   traditional blocking queue data
>   structure, except that the underlying
>   data storage mechanism is abstracted
>   away as an `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`.

But nothing specifically says that things will be removed in the same order they're added.

Anybody know for sure?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Well, `BlockingCollection<T>` is really designed for parallel work, where you have multiple simulataneous "producers" and one consumer (using GetConsumingEnumerable()).

In this situation, you have no way to guarantee insertion order, so the ordering constraints aren't specified.

That being said, `BlockingCollection<T>` works upon any `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>` (specified in the constructor).  If you don't provide one in the constructor, internally, it will use a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`.  This causes it to be FIFO, since it will actually be (internally) a queue.  So yes, by default, it will be "guaranteed to be strictly FIFO if used in a single-producer, single-consumer fashion", at least in the current implementation. If you want to force this for future proofing (since the queue is an implementation detail), just construct it as:

```
var blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<MyClass>(new ConcurrentQueue<MyClass>());
```

That will guarantee that it uses a queue now, and in the future (since the queue is an implementation detail).

Comment: I'm not convinced that the existence of `GetConsumingEnumerable` implies that the collection is intended for multiple producers and a single consumer. Granted, that particular method appears to be intended for a single consumer, but that certainly doesn't prevent multiple consumers.

Comment: @Jim: It doesn't -but that was the main motivation behind that.  Multiple consumers were intended via AddToAny(), where each of the relevant BlockingCollections were used by a single consumer.  Event the name itself "BlockingCollection" is suggesting that it "blocks" (on the consumer side) until items are added.

Comment: You answered my immediate question, preventing me from having to IDASM it myself.  Thanks.

Comment: Question about specifying an instance of an IProducerConsumerCollection; can that nested collection be used independently? Say I don't want to block producers for any reason when adding to a queue, but I do want to block the consumer(s) when there's nothing to dequeue. Could I Enqueue() using the ConcurrentQueue that I've wrapped and then take (dequeue) using the BlockingCollection? Or is blocking during an Add() on an unbounded BlockingCollection not an issue?

Comment: @KeithS If it's unbounded, Add() won't block, so its a non-issue.

Comment: @ReedCopsey , trying to implement the simple BlockingCollection usage without a while(true) and TryTake(). I was going to use GetConsumingEnumerable() but this is killing me ... per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460684%28v=vs.110%29.aspx "...There is no guarantee that the items are enumerated in the same order in which they are added by the producer threads."  What's the point of having a ConcurrentQUEUE if I can't enumerate and guarantee order?  I need to have the items processed sequentially.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @DaveBlack The enumeration order depends on the underlying data structure.  BlockingCollection<T> isn't necessarily a queue - though the default happens to be one.  If you only have one producer thread, you'll be fine - if you have multiple ones, there's no way to guarantee that you won't get 2 threads inserting at "the same time", in which case, you'd have no way to know which order those two items should be enumerated, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps MSDN documentation has been updated since this question but it now clearly states that BlockingCollection will default to FIFO unless otherwise directed.

see:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371(v=vs.110).aspx
or in case MS change the link google 'MSDN BlockingCollection Overview'

NET Framework 4.6 and 4.5

Look for 'Specifying the Collection Type' on that page.