# WCF webservice - is using lock going to cause problems?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, web-services, locking

We have a WCF web service operation that is used to generate PDF files. We're using a 3rd party tool to do that (Syncfusion specifically) which we may not be able to replace at the moment.

The problem is that it seems that 3rd party tool has a problem with multi-threading and doesn't work in some cases when there's multiple calls to the web service at the same time.

We can get rid of the problem by using `lock` and making sure that only one thread executes the critical section:

```
Public Class GeneratorController
{
    // object we use for lock
    private static Object thisLock = new Object();

    public void Generate(ref PdfDocument pdfDocument)
    {
        lock (thisLock)
        {
             // critical section
        }
    }
}
```

My questions is: is that a good idea? Is it going to cause any problems if we have a code like that in a web service?

**Note**

This is not a question about Syncfusion. This is a question about using `lock` in a web service. Do not change tags to syncfusion, please.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Syncfusion - is it possible to create multiple concurrent instances of the object?  I would think if you have distinct instances you wouldn't need to lock.

Comment: I though so too but it seems to be the problem. Maybe they're using something static in their code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WCF supports synchronized calling of your service objects, depending on your needs, you may want to look into the following two properties:

- ServiceBehavior.InstanceContextMode:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx
- ServiceBehavior.ConcurrencyMode:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode.aspx

If you cannot launch multiple instances of 3rd party component, and the component does not allow concurrent acccess (the worst case), then you can specify InstanceContextMode = Single, and ConcurrencyMode = Single; In this case, WCF will only instantiate a single copy of your WCF object (which I assume is a wrapper around 3rd party component), and only one request is processed at a time. The requests will be queued up and processed in a FIFO manner. You don't have to use lock inside your wcf service, since the WCF runtime makes sure you have synchronized access to your wcf objects.

Answer (score 7):

The problem I see here is resource starvation.

There is no FIFO rule surrounding locks. So if there's a continuous load, you could get this scenario:

- Thread `A` claims the lock
- Thread `B` waits for the lock
- Thread `C` waits for the lock
- Thread `A` releases the lock. The lock is arbitrarily given to thread `C`
- Thread `D` waits for the lock. Now you have thread `B` and `D` both waiting.
- Thread `C` releases the lock. Even through thread `B` has been waiting the longest, the lock is arbitrarily given to thread `D`.

And so it continues until the WCF call times out,  and you get an impossible-to-reproduce error.

If I had to implement this, I would have a single worker thread dedicated to generating the PDF files. This thread would be launched when the service first starts up, and it waits to pick up a job off a job queue.  Each WCF query will place a request on this queue, and there will be some way it can block until it knows the job has been processed.

.NET 4.0 provides the `BlockingCollection` class to help with this. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825275/does-blockingcollectiont-guarantee-removal-order))

This gives you the approach without a complete solution because it isn't a trivial problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's that kind of information I was looking for. The process in our case is rather infrequent but that kind of starving could still possibly happen. I will take it into account.

Answer (score 0):

Essential PDF is a thread safe component
, so it is possible to create the PDF document in multi-threaded state. Can you please create a Direct-trac incident in order to get the solution.

Comment: Well, we still struggle to obtain a properly working version from Syncfusion so that's not really true.